System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out exactly 5 minutes
I am working with a C# Windows application that connects to a Java API hosted on a Tomcat server. The API exposes two different methods. We've encountered an issue with the SteamExecute method timing out exactly after 5 minutes when processing XML files around 100 MB in size. However, the other method, Execute, works fine without any timeout errors. We've attempted to adjust the timeout settings on Tomcat, but the issue persists. Any insights or ideas on how to resolve this?
